# e4rat in Fedora 15

Tags: fedora, boot, ext4

Has anyone tried installing [e4rat](http://e4rat.sourceforge.net/) and optimizing boot-time in *Fedora 15*? This ext4 defragmenting and optimizing utility works wonderfully in *Debian*. I am wondering if someone has replaced *Fedora*'s native `readahead-fedora` with `e4rat` and compared the results.

Reference: [Lifehacker's e4rat article](http://lifehacker.com/5790311/e4rat-cuts-your-linux-pcs-boot-time-in-half-with-a-few-simple-commands).

Answer (score 1):

Fedora15 has got systemd, as a drop-in replacement for SysV boot style init scripts. This aggressively parallelises the boot time in Fedora15. Look for systemd on wikipedia for further links.

Although, still would be curious to know the results of e4rat on a Fedora15 machine in a systemd era.

Comment: @ArielSonique how has been your experience with systemd, just checking...

Comment: that discussion would be best brought to http://chat.stackexchange.com/, as this isn't a discussion forum and the comments aren't really meant for that kind of back and forth.